# How can I specified a browser in golang webview?

Tags: go

I need build native app in windows, but in some case, I need integrate an IE to call active X plugin,  so I use [zserge/webview](https://github.com/zserge/webview) to open the page. but webview use EDG by default in window 10, my question is. How can I specify IE webview?

Comment: I don't have Windows and can't try this myself, but reading the documentation and issue queue of Webview it is stated that it uses MSHTML (IE10 or IE11) on Windows. There is work in progress to make it support Edge, and that is not yet finished, see: https://github.com/zserge/webview/issues/85 . Are you sure it's using Edge? Maybe you're having a different issue - such ActiveX controls being disabled for security reasons?

Comment: Thanks for you comments, By use JavaScript web browser test, the results is Edge, from now on,I don’t have solutions to deal this issue, so I change to use C# to implement the requirements